# Deep Link with Push Notification - FCM - Android

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, android-push-notification

**What I want:** I want to send push notification to users. When user tap on that notification, user should navigate to specific activity.

**What I did:** I created one deep link in Firebase console. I implemented **FirebaseInstanceIdService** & **FirebaseMessagingService** as well. I'm able to catch Firebase message which I sent from Firebase console.

**What is the issue:** I'm not able to catch the dynamic link what I have created in Firebase console.

My code is like below.

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private final String TAG = "MyFirebaseInstanceID";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private final String TAG = "MyFbaseMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Log.e(TAG, "\nmessage: " + message);

        sendNotification(message);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String message) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestDeepLinkActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

**Firebase Console Image**

[image: Firebase Console Image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Solution:**

- I have to add intent-filter in an activity in manifest file to which I want to go, on-tapping of push notification. This notification will have some url which is being called deeplink in Android Terminology. You can refer below link for more about deeplink.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

- I was using these two links as a deeplink: "www.somedomain.com/about" & "www.somedomain.com/app".
- Please do not add **http** or **https** in intent-filter, they are not supported. Chekout [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158775/discussion-between-milen-and-arshad) conversation for more clarification. I'm putting an image of that chat as well, If in case in future the link gets expire.

[image]

- Please refer below code for how I'm passing deeplink to NotificationManager. intent-filter aumatically intercept and launch that particular activity.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```java
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        String title = data.get("title");
        String message = data.get("message");
        String deepLink = data.get("deepLink");

        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.setTitle(title);
        notification.setMessage(message);
        notification.setDeepLink(deepLink);

        sendNotification(this, title, message, deepLink);
    }

    public static void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String message, String deepLink) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("any_default_id", "any_channel_name",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Any description can be given!");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(android.app.Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(deepLink));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        notificationBuilder
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".mvp.view.activity.ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.somedomain.com"
            android:path="/about"
            android:scheme="app" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.somedomain.com"
            android:path="/contact"
            android:scheme="app" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Extra:**

- If you want to receive some more data(i.e userId or loanId) in that activity, you can pass it to while sending push notification from your server(i.e back-end or web based dashboard). You can do like below.

  ```
  {
   "data": {
   "userId": "65431214564651251456",
   "deepLink": "www.somedomain.com/app",
   "title": "This is title!",
   "message": "This is message!"
   },
  "to": "FCM token here"
  }
  ```
- **Important: Below JSON will not work, this is for reference only. This is also nowhere mentioned in documentation. So kindly take care of it. Correct JSON is above.**

```
{
    "to": "FCM Token here",
        "notification": {
            "Body": "This week’s edition is now available.",
            "title": "NewsMagazine.com",
            "icon": "new"
        },
        "data": {
            "title": "This is title!",
            "message": "This is message!"
    }
}
```

- You can receive extra data(i.e userId or loanId) in method **onMessageReceived** of **MyFirebaseMessagingService** class like below.

```java
String userId = data.get("userId");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, userId);
```

- And in that activity you can write like below in onCreate method.

```java
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    String intentStringExtra = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (intentStringExtra != null) {
        userId = intentStringExtra;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation : in your answer might make conflict in this`<data
            android:host="www.somedomain.com"
            android:path="/contact"
            android:scheme="app" />`
we use android:scheme="app" for open specific activity and android:scheme="https" for specific url. refer that link which you have attached.

Comment: onMessageReceived() is only executed if the app is opened. So in other situations (I think about 90% of the time!) the push notification will not work for deep linking.

Comment: @PayamRoozbahaniFard That's when if you send a 'notification' message or a 'notification + data' message. If 'data message is sent (handled by you), onMessageReceived is triggered (no matter foreground or background)

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e You mean if the server sends data then onMessageReceived will get called everytime doesn't matter if your app is in the foreground or in the background?

Comment: @MaulikDodia Yes, if your server ONLY sends 'data'  (and NOT 'notification') in the fcm payload, then yes onMessageReceived will be called everytime. Reference [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)

Comment: Could you show the json for the fcm with a deep link?